# IE7 float bug in IE10 Compatability mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to get a site working in IE10 for those people who've pressed the compatibility mode button - usually by mistake!

Compatibility mode in IE10 renders the document for IE7

I have a container div with 1 to 4 columns of dives floated left inside it, they are all cleared by a clearing div after the last column div.

It all works fine except in IE10 Compatability mode. I think it is an IE7 float bug but I could be wrong

[You can see the issue here](http://www.ballinafoxstreetpreschool.org.au/dev/newsletter/)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:hidden` or a clearfix...? 1+ for the pictures.

Comment: Thanks Josh, an overflow:auto was the solution, glad you like the pics :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your div

```
<div class="year-wrap 1">
```

for this one

```
<div class="year-wrap 1" style="overflow: auto;">
```

or simply add this in the class year-wrap of your css

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Morgul you are a legend :), I just added overflow:auto and it works fine now. The bottom margin of the 'year-wrap' is ignored in IE7 but it is good enough. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also put this on the `<head>` section of your website:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

With this, the Compatibility mode button will not be shown so you won't worry about people accidentally clicking the Compatibility mode button. :)

Comment: @morktron You're welcome. I have come across with this problem on Comaptibility mode before so I just want to share this solution that I've found. :)